# Android's method of loading bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, dpi

I have an application that loads Bitmaps from my Assets folder.
I use decodeStream() to get them and then I use createScaledBitmaps() to scale them to the appropriate size.
If I have an image thats 50x50 in physical pixels, and a density of 160dpi, and I'm on a screen that has a density of 320dpi, will Android automatically scale up the density for my Bitmap by a factor of 2 (i.e from 160dpi to 320dpi) for Bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When you decode a bitmap, dpi doesn't matter.  Only width and height.  SO you'll have a 50x50 pixel image.  When you draw that image, you can scale it if you want.

Comment: dpi does matter A LOT for a Bitmap

Comment: I can have a 50x50 image and set a lowDensity it will look very bad quality. But if I set high density or that of equal to the screen than the image will look better.

Comment: It matters for display, but not for decoding.  A 50 pixel wide bitmap is a 50 pixel wide bitmap.  If you don't scale it up it will be half the size when drawn.

Comment: I see what your saying now, thanx.